# Как правильно фильтровать список по полям ? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, filter, lodash

Помогите разобраться с фильтрацией по полям в ReactJs.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально я пытался просто привести их все к нижнему регистру,  но ведь это не работает для чисел и полей в которых есть смешанный тип данных.
Использовал Lodash.
Делал вот так

```
var result = data.filter((item) => {
  return 
   item["id"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
   item["status"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
   item["token"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
   item["currency"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
   item["redirect_success_url"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
   item["redirect_fail_url"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
   item["amount"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
   item["created_at"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
   item["updated_at"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
   item["extra_return_param"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
   item["extra_return_param"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
   item["operation_type"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
   item["order_number"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
   item["card_masked_number"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
   item["uid"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
});

if (!result.length) {
  result = this.state.data;
}
return result;
```

}

Варианты с Number() и parseInt() не принесли результата, извините за мой вопрос, я впервые использую React и с JS я только знакомлюсь.

Comment: Не мучайте себя. Начните с малого. Одно поле, фильтр, поиск, отображение, затем второе комбинации, тип и т.д.

Comment: Вот например так тоже не работает return item["id"].includes(search);

Comment: Попробуйте тогда такую функцию https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_search.asp

Comment: И что вы передали в search и какие значение в id

Comment: Вот, попробовал с строкой. return item["status"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()); это поле - строка, как на скрине что я прикрепил выше видно, что в нем есть пока что только один вариант - approved. Если я не ошибаюсь search работает по всему документу const { data, search } = this.state; В этом случае ничего не происходит но и ошибки о том что .includes не является функцией нет.

Comment: Я ссылку прикрепил для того чтобы вы могли посмотреть

Comment: С строкой получилось, фильтрует, с вашей ссылкой ознакомился но пока что-то не могу понять как ею воспользоваться что бы получить значения передаваемые в id.

Comment: Тут можно воспользоваться toString

Comment: item["id"].toString().contains...

Comment: item["id"].toString().includes(search.toString()) || ,этот вариант я попробовал в первую очередь, работает если нет других фильтров, если я добавляю фильтр например по статусу все лмоается :(

Comment: Как быть со смешанным типом данных например ссылкой ? тоже приводить к строке ? или например если значение null

Comment: if (!result.length || !result || result === null || result === ''") {
      result = this.state.data;
    }
    return result;
не помогает и вываливается в ошибку TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null